# Furnace fan turns off when compressor turns on; unit freeze up

Tags: fans, blower

I have a goodman HVAC (model: GMS950904CXA). The unit froze up the other day. When I turn the thermostat to cool, the compressor turns on, the furnace blower fan turns on for a few seconds and then shuts down. When I turn compressor off and leave the fan on, the blower fan works fine and will keep running. I have replaced the run capacitor and also the control board. It did not solve the problem. I have turned the motor by hand and it seems to rotate freely. My unit does not have an overflow switch. Is the motor dying? Is freon low? What could be the problem?

---

I think I figured out at least part of the problem. My blower motor has 4 speeds. There are 4 wires from highest speed to lowest speed (black, blue, orange, red). I measured the resistance of the motor at each wire and they all looked good. The cool terminal on the board is connected to the black wire (highest speed). The heat terminal on the board is connected to the blue wire (2nd highest speed). I measured the voltage at the control board as well. When I turn on the fan only, only the heat terminal (not the cool) shows 120V. When I turn the thermostat to cool, then only the cool terminal (not heat) shows 120V. Because the fan runs ok when only fan is called by the thermostat, but it shuts down when cooling is called, it tells me that the connection of the black wire can be loose. It explains the symptoms I described in my question. Once the fan turns on during cooling, it becomes loose and shuts itself down. I confirmed this by switching the black wire to the heat terminal on the control board. After the switch, when only fan is called, the fan starts fine but shuts down after a few seconds. So I think I have nailed it down to the black wire. The resistance for the black wire is ok (~ 2 ohms) and the connection at the control board is tight and ok. My question is: can this be caused by a loose connection of the black wire at the motor end? I have not taken the motor out yet. I just want to hear you guys' options before I do that.

Comment: It is possible that the Freon is low or ur drain is stopped up making it freeze up not circulating right

Comment: You need to quit throwing parts at it and troubleshoot the problem. Since you don’t have an alarm is your blower motor 2 speed , we usually cool at a higher fan speed and the control relay for speed 2 may have failed or the motor motor being less common.  The Goodman units I have worked on are some what bare bones the control of the fan is a relay driven by the thermostat that’s why I ask about 2 speed. Low Freon has nothing to do with the fan the unit will ice up because of low air flow. Does your unit have a fan bypass switch to turn the fan on all the time? Find the relay for high speed.

Comment: Problem solved. Finally I replaced the blower motor. Problem solved.